# Checking for template errors of an Angular app without bundling

Tags: angular, parsing, compilation, continuous-integration, angular-cli

We have a CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab that runs on every commit where want to check the project for Typescript and template (mainly template) errors. We are currently using `ng build --prod` but it takes forever because it is also bundling the source code (currently 20min. On my machine it takes 2 min).

**Is it possible to run only the 'first part' of the `ng build --prod` where it only checks only for Typescript and template errors?** This will make our pipeline faster.

Comment: Have you read https://angular.io/cli/build? That outlines the options you have for running `ng build`.

Comment: I checked every option there. I don't see one that will do just checking.

Comment: Does that answer your question, then?

Comment: The question is answered, yes, but the problem still exists, unfortunately.